# ¿Como hago un archivo log en el cual guarde cada evento que desee de mi sistema?

Tags: java

Lo que llevo es lo siguiente:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
FileHandler fh;  

try {  
    fh = new FileHandler(file_log);  
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

    logger.info("Primera prueba");  
    logger.info("¿Todo bien?");

} catch (SecurityException | IOException ex) {  
    ex.printStackTrace();  
}
```

El problema de eso es que me elimina lo anterior. Yo quisiera agregar eventos y no sustituir los anteriores.

Comment: No se casi nada de Java, pero una busqueda rapida me devolvio que para el FileHandler hay un constructor que recibe un segundo parametro boolean, imagino que si es true lo que pasara es que añadiras al archivo en vez de sobreescribirlo. Encontre la info aca: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

Comment: @Kenny hermano, gracias llevaba rato buscando. Colocalo como respuesta para darle la aprobación.

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudo. Saludos :D

Comment: Creo que en lugar de implementar esto a mano, puedes usar un framework que soporte el logging de manera asíncrona y mande el resultado a un archivo. Ejemplos: log4j2, logback, etc...

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ y si lo agregas como respuesta en colaboración al foro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el objeto `FileHandler` existe un constructor que recibe un segundo parámetro de tipo `boolean`. Si este argumento es `True`, se añadira al archivo todo lo que indiques sin sobreescribir lo que ya esta dentro de el.

```
fh = new FileHandler(file_log, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa más limpia, sencilla y que ya está comprobada por muchos proyectos y múltiples usos es la de usar librerías que provean funcionalidad de logging, sin necesidad de usar el logging nativo de Java (que sinceramente deja mucho que desear).

Algunas de las librerías más populares para Java son [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) y [logback](https://logback.qos.ch). Estas librerías poseen, por lo menos:

- Configurar el nivel de log de la aplicación.
- Configurar el nivel de log a aplicar a un paquete o paquetes. Este puede ser diferente al nivel de log de la aplicación. Por ejemplo, tu aplicación en general puede tener un nivel de log de INFO pero las librerías de Spring (por mencionar alguna) pueden tener un nivel de log de WARN o ERROR, así tu log no se llena de contenido innecesario para su revisión.
- Estrategias de salida de log. Por ejemplo: escribir en consola, en archivo, en base de datos, mandar el log por un servicio, etc.
- Estrategias de formato de salida de los mensajes de log. Por ejemplo: `[fecha y hora] [nivel de log] [nombre de clase] [nombre de hilo] <mensaje> [salto de línea]`. Te permite personalizar esta salida y que sea homogénea para todos los mensajes de log.
- La inicialización del logger es relativamente sencilla. Basta con tener un código similar a esto:

  ```
  public class MiClase {
      private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MiClase.class);
  }
  ```
- Puedes configurar estrategias para almacenar el log. Por ejemplo, `RollingFileAppender` permite que se cree un archivo de log diario con el nombre base del log (p.e. miapp), la fecha del log (p.e. 2017-08-28) y el número de log del día (p.e. 1, 2, etc). Ejemplos: miapp-2017-08-28.log, miapp-2017-08-28-1.log, miapp-2017-08-28-2.log, y así (esto en caso que se haya reiniciado la aplicación y se vuelva a ejecutar el mismo día, no se elimina el log anterior ni se escribe en él. Todo esto es configurable, de acuerdo a tus necesidades).

Cabe resaltar que existe un framework llamado [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org). Su nombre completo es Simple Logging Facade for Java. Ojo, el nombre indica que este framework no es para logging, sino es una **fachada de logging**. Es decir, este framework no hace la labor de logging, sino que es una capa intermedia entre tu aplicación y un framework de logging. ¿Para qué sirve esto? Bueno, es una forma de que tu aplicación pueda soportar el cambio de uso de framework de log de acuerdo a tus necesidades. Por ejemplo, puede que hoy en día estés delegando el log a JUL (Java Util Logger, el logging nativo de Java) y luego decidas cambiar a uno de los frameworks mencionados previamente. SLF4J te permite, tras cambiar unos jars, que el cambio sea transparente a nivel de tu aplicación y de código. Esto ofrece grandes ventajas puesto que tu código se abstrae del framework como tal y solo te amarras a la fachada. La fachada se puede asociar a cualquier otro framework, siempre y cuando implementen el puente (bridge) que permita dicha integración.

Comment: Gracias hermano. Muy bien explicado.

Comment: De nada. Espero que puedas probar alguno de ellos y evitar hacer un log a mano. Es mucha labor, y configurar un log como logback no toma más de 10 minutos y lo tienes andando.